# How can I avoid circular imports in routes file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm attempting to organize my routes file into multiple files but cannot access an "enum" object declared in the primary file due it not having been declared yet.

In the example below, I get the error `ReferenceError: Cannot access 'MenuItem' before initialization`.

I thought it was strange that the function (createRoute) does not cause the same error, so it does get declared before the routesSettings file calls it.

Is there any trick that would allow me to keep the structure I'm aiming for?

*routes.js*

```
import Home from "../pages/Home";
import Settings from "../pages/settings";

import { routesSettings } from "./routesSettings"

export const MenuItem = Object.freeze({
    HOME: "Home",
    SETTINGS: "Settings",
});

export const routes = [
    // Home
    createRoute(MenuItem.HOME, "/", Home),
    // Settings
    createRoute(MenuItem.SETTINGS, "/", SETTINGS),
    ...routesSettings,
]

export function createRoute(name, route, component) {
    return { name, route, component };
}
```

*routesSettings.js*

```
import PasswordSettings from "../pages/settings/password";
import UserSettings from "../pages/settings/user";

import { createRoute, MenuItem } from "./routes"

export const routesSettings = [
    createRoute(MenuItem.SETTINGS_PASSWORD, "/settings/password", PasswordSettings),
    createRoute(MenuItem.SETTINGS_USER, "/settings/password", UserSettings),
];
```

Comment: Put `MenuItem` into its own file and imported into your files here

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are see this error:
**ReferenceError: Cannot access 'MenuItem' before initialization**

is because you imported `MenuItem` in your `routesSettings.js` file; typically during compile time the JS engine will hoist all *variable* declarations in your lexical environment with `undefined` and they all remain `uninitialized` and only only gets initialized during the actual evaluation of the code.

Try console logging `MenuItems` in your `routesSettings.js` file, you'll see that it's value it's actually undefined in that file?

However, you'll notice that `createRoute` function didn't throw any errors...the reason is because function declarations in JS are added to the memory during compile which we can use before the actual function's declaration.
Typically, the JS engine looks into the lexical environment where it finds the function and executes it.

Also, if you change your `createRoute` function to:

```
export const createRoute = (name, route, component) => {
    return { name, route, component };
};
```

you'll have errors like `createRoute is undefined etc..` because `const` remain `uninitialized`, hence `undefined` in your lexical environment. Function expressions aren't hoisted either `const neverHoisted = function(){...}`.

In summary, JS only hoist declarations and not assignments/initializations.

What you need to do solve the issues you are seeing is to create a separate file for `menuItem` and import it in `router.js` and `routeSettings.js` files.